# Creating a new project in Git from terminal and later updating

Tags: git, github, terminal

So, my terminal only likes to *sometimes* update my git hub, what could be going on, or what am I doing wrong? I am using it to push a rails app in this example, here is what I typed to push to github.

```
$ rails new my-app
$ cd my-app
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Username/my-app.git
$ git remote -v
$ git push origin master
```

This works, to usually start a project, but it also requires me to make the repo on GitHub prior to the commit/push.

Is there a way I can create the repo as I push the new app?

My second part of this is pushing to add a commit to the project, for instance I typed this:

```
$ cd my-app
$ git add . 
$ git commit -m "Adds Posts Model, View, and Controller"
```

Which returns this text:  `11 files changed, 75 insertions(+), 56 deletions(-)`
But I still have no new commit/update in the project on GitHub. 
[image: No New Commit]

---

I am using a 2014 MacBook Pro OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can create the repo as I push the new app?

No. The terminal doesn't know what is on the receiving end of `https://github.com/Username/my-app.git`, and likewise github.com doesn't know that you will be pushing a repo and expect a repo to be made on demand. That just doesn't work like that.

Luckily it only takes a couple of minutes to create a project on github and reference it locally.

> My second part of this is pushing to add a commit to the project, for
>   instance I typed this:
>
> ```
> $ cd my-app
> $ git add . 
> $ git commit -m "Adds Posts Model, View, and Controller"
> ```
>
> Which returns this text:  `11 files changed, 75 insertions(+), 56
>   deletions(-)` But I still have no new commit/update in the project on
>   GitHub.

A commit is a local operation. To get it to the remote on github, you need to push it:

```
$ git push origin master
```

for instance.

Comment: Oh, so all I was really missing what the `$git push origin master` ?

Comment: @ether for the second part of your question, yes

Comment: I see, still just kind of learning all of this, appreciate the help! (will accept answer when timer goes down)

Comment: @ether Git is said to have a steep learning curve, so good luck :-) there are many useful questions and answers about basic git stuff here on SO for you to have a look at

Comment: Just sent my second commit through, everything seems to be working, thanks!